# Is it even possible to represent the decimal 129 in 8-Bit Sign-Magnitude Format?

Tags: binary

Is this a trick question? I doubt it, but it's really odd because the maximum positive decimal value that can be represented in **8-Bit Sign-Magnitude Format** is 127.

So, when I'm asked such questions, should I simply state that it's not possible or is there a way?

Comment: It depends on what 'represent' means. For example, if no negative numbers are used in the problem domain then they can be used to 'represent' such a positive value.

Comment: Negative numbers are also used. For instance, replace 129 in the question with -135. How about now?

Comment: Such a number cannot be 'directly represented'; for the reason stated in the question.

Comment: So, you need 16 bits for the signed representation of such numbers, then?

Comment: If keeping with such a format and direct representation, 9 bits would suffice.